# C: Search for chars in LIST

Tags: c, list, search, struct, char

I have a hard time making the codes for functions that include searching char elements in a LIST. When I run the program, it always shows blank for a result (as shown on case 4) and it only works, if I search for an int element. (Case 2 and 3 aren't finished.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 80
#define LOOPS 2
struct delivery
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    char code[8];
    char info[80];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int amount;
};
typedef struct delivery BODY;
struct List{
    BODY body;
    struct List*pNext;
};
typedef struct List LIST;
int enterBody(BODY*ps);
void printBody(BODY s);
void printList(LIST*pFirst);
LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody);
int mean_Subject(LIST *pFirst);
void searchGroup(LIST*pFirst, char gr);

int main()
{
    FILE*pOut = NULL, *pIn = NULL;
    char Fname[] = "List_bin.dat";
    BODY newbody;
    LIST*pFirst = NULL, *p;
    int res, i, mode;
    int sfn;
    char gr;
    int newgr, fn;
    BODY delivery;
    char*menu[] = { "MENU:",
        "1 - Enter info for new delivery ",
        "2 - Print info for deliveries for an entered month ",
        "3 - Total delivery amount for an entered product ",
        "4 - Show providers for an entered product ",
    };
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("\n%s\n", menu[i]);
        do
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nChoose operation (1-4): ");
            res = scanf("%d", &mode);
        } while (res != 1);
        switch (mode)
        {
        case 1:
            for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++)
            {
                res = enterBody(&delivery);
                if (res != 1)
                {
                    printf("Error in initialization %d\n", res);
                    break;
                }
                p = insertBegin(pFirst, delivery);
                if (p == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Not enough memory! ");
                    break;
                }
                pFirst = p;
            }
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            if (pFirst != NULL)
            {
                printList(pFirst);
            }
            else printf("\nEmpty list!\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            if (pFirst != NULL)
                printf("Total delivered amount: %d\n", mean_Subject(pFirst));
            else
                printf("\nEmpty list!\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\nEnter name of product: ");
            scanf("%s", &gr);
            if (pFirst != NULL)
                searchGroup(pFirst, gr);
            else
                printf("Empty list\n");
            system("pause");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nIncorrect operation!\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    } while (mode != 11);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int enterBody(BODY*ps)
{
    if (ps == NULL) return 0;
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(BODY));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter delivery number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->num));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter name of product: ");
    gets(ps->name);
    printf("\nEnter provider code: ");
    gets(ps->code);
    printf("\nEnter provider's company, address and phone number: ");
    gets(ps->info);
    printf("\nEnter date: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->day));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter month: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->month));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter year: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->year));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter amount delivered: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->amount));
    fflush(stdin);
    return 1;
}

void printBody(BODY s)
{
    printf("\nNumber: %d\tName: %s\tCode: %s\tInfo: %s\nDate: %d-%d-%d\tAmount: %d",
        s.num, s.name, s.code, s.info, s.day, s.month, s.year, s.amount);;
}

void printList(LIST*pFirst)
{
    LIST*p = NULL;
    if (pFirst == NULL) printf("Empty list.\n");
    else
    {

        p = pFirst;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printBody(p->body);
            p = p->pNext;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody)
{
    LIST*p;
    p = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p->body = newBody;
        p->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = p;
        return p;
    }
}

int mean_Subject(LIST *pFirst)
{
    LIST *p;
    int mean = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (pFirst == NULL)
        printf("Empty list\n");
    else
    {
        p = pFirst;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            sum += p->body.amount;
            count++;
            p = p->pNext;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void searchGroup(LIST*pFirst, char gr)
{
    LIST*p;
    p = pFirst;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->body.name == gr)
            printf("&s", p->body.info);
        p = p->pNext;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &gr);` --> `scanf("%c", &gr);`, `if (p->body.name == gr)` --> `if (p->body.name[0] == gr)`

Comment: or `char gr;` --> `char gr[20];`, --> `void searchGroup(LIST*pFirst, char gr[]);`,  --> `scanf("%19s", gr);`, --> `if(strcmp(p->body.name, gr) == 0)`